# What is the name of the song that plays at 12:40 in Noragami Aragoto episode 7?

Tags: noragami

Really want to know the name of this accoustic guitar song. I've searched it at YouTube to no avail.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Noragami Aragoto* soundtrack ["Noragami no Oto 2"](http://vgmdb.net/album/56225), disc 2, track #6 "Tasogare".

Here is a 20-second extract from the beginning of the piece: https://clyp.it/oz5kfpym.

Comment: This is exactly it! Thank you so much for the answer. Hionestly I didn't expect it. Thank you again!